# Map viewmodel to entity from EF using Automapper while ignore null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to map a viewmodel to an entity from EF. I have gotten so far that I can map all properties from the viewmodel to the entity but I am trying to ignore all properties that is null (the data in the viewmodel comes from a form and I don't want to put `null` as the pk for example). I want to be able to do something like this:

```
IUserDetails objUserDetails = GetDataFromForm();
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
user.UpdateUser(objUserDetails);
```

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
public static class UserExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateUser(this IUser user, IUserDetails userDetails)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<IUserDetails, IUser>()
                .UseDestinationValue()
                .IgnoreNullValues()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AddressLine1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address1))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AddressLine2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address2))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserGUID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GUID));
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        mapper.Map<IUserDetails, IUser>(userDetails, user);
    }

    private static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> UseDestinationValue<TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
    {
        expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
        return expression;
    }
    private static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> IgnoreNullValues<TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
    {
        expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcVal, destVal, c) => { Debugger.Break(); return srcVal != null; }));
        return expression;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have put a breakpoint in `IgnoreNullValues()` and when I debug the code I can see that `srcVal` is never anything else than `null`, however all the other values looks good. What am I missing?

## Update:

Apparently this is due to a [bug in 5.1.1](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1634), downgrading to 5.0.2 made it all work.

Comment: If this is a bug in 5.1.1, Have you raised the bug in Github so that they will fix it in the next release.

Comment: @Silly John The blue text in the bottom line is a link going to the issue on Github ;)

Comment: i did not notice the hyperlink.. :)

Comment: @Silly John I tried to decide whether to embed it or not, next time I wont (unless SO changes their styling so it stands out more).